# Calculating total of a column in sql

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to calculate sum of amount in sql.I am using java POJO classes.Now i am writing query like this

```
    "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM fundraisingusers ";
```

But it is displaying error as Could not find setter for SUM(amount) on class com.lh.alumni.dto.FundraisingUsers.How to add getter and setter for SUM in my Java pojo class?

Here is my pojo class

```
public class FundraisingUsers implements Serializable{
    private Integer fundraisinguserId;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "fundraisinguserId")
    public Integer getFundraisinguserId() {
    return fundraisinguserId;
    }

    public void setFundraisinguserId(Integer fundraisinguserId) {
    this.fundraisinguserId = fundraisinguserId;
    }

    @Column(name = "amount")
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your pojo class?

Comment: How do you construct and execute that query? As a native sql query, a jsql query or are you sing some criteria api?

Comment: I am having dao and service layers.from dao i am executing the query

Comment: You seem to be using a framework that maps SQL result columns to object setters. Please, tell us which framework you are using.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I think he is using hibernate.

Comment: Yes hibernate i am using

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong in the question to be downvoted.

Comment: @SachinHR 4 months after you asked your question: is this problem fixed? Did my answer work? Is there anything left why you did not accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to do is, you want to get the sum of all users amount.

The problem here is, you try to get a `fundraisingusers`-object and assign the amount to the sum of all users amounts to each user. This is wrong.

What you can do is:

```
SELECT amount FROM fundraisingusers;
```

and for all models you get you can then build the sum on code-side.

or you could try building a pojo with getter/setter like

```
private BigDecimal sumamount;

@Column(name = "sumamount")
public BigDecimal getSumAmount() {
    return this.sumamount;
}

public void setSumAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.sumamount= sumamount;
}
```

and the query is

```
SELECT sum(amount) as SumAmount FROM fundraisingusers;
```

Comment: It is showing error for setSumAmount like this method must return BigDecimal

Comment: @SachinHR what db-type is your `amount`-column?

Comment: It is of type BigDecimal

Comment: what is your exact exception you get

Comment: Can u please tell should i have to create another field in pojo as private BigDecimal SumAmount?

Comment: @SachinHR yeah I updated my answer. You should create a new field. otherwise you (at least) will get wrong data

Comment: This method must return a result of type BigDecimal

Comment: change returntype of setSumAmount to void. my fault